# Easiest way to replace row values by another dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in python and I prefer to use R.

I want to replace specific rows by other dataframe, so what I do is the following:

## My code

```
xgb=pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0]]*18,columns=["0","1","2"])
xgb.iloc[8:12,:]=pd.DataFrame([[0.36950416, 0.08233581, 0.54816002]]*4,columns=xgb.columns)
```

I also have tried `xgb[8:12]`, `xgb.loc[8:11,:]`, and what I get is.

## Result

```
xgb
      0    1    2
0   0.0  0.0  0.0
1   0.0  0.0  0.0
2   0.0  0.0  0.0
3   0.0  0.0  0.0
4   0.0  0.0  0.0
5   0.0  0.0  0.0
6   0.0  0.0  0.0
7   0.0  0.0  0.0
8   NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN  NaN
12  0.0  0.0  0.0
13  0.0  0.0  0.0
14  0.0  0.0  0.0
15  0.0  0.0  0.0
16  0.0  0.0  0.0
17  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

How can I do it giving the indexes of the row I want change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpliest is set by list (with same length like columns):

```
xgb=pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0]]*18,columns=["0","1","2"])
xgb.iloc[8:12,:]=[0.36950416, 0.08233581, 0.54816002]
print (xgb)
           0         1        2
0   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
1   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
2   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
3   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
4   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
5   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
6   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
7   0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
8   0.369504  0.082336  0.54816
9   0.369504  0.082336  0.54816
10  0.369504  0.082336  0.54816
11  0.369504  0.082336  0.54816
12  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
13  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
14  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
15  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
16  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
17  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000
```

Your solution working with set `index` values by slicing for same index values like sliced rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.36950416, 0.08233581, 0.54816002]],
                   columns=xgb.columns, 
                   index=xgb.index[8:12])
xgb.iloc[8:12,:]=df
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if the values are not always the same? I want to replace the rows by another dataframe

Comment: Thank you, can I know why I have to add the specific index in the dataframe? is there a way to replace it without do that? PD: I acepted an answer a few minutes ago and I still cannot acept your answer, so I will do it as soon as SO allows me.

Comment: @DannyHern - Because if not same index values then are created missing values.